# React - move to another html page - with conditional if

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

When I call fetch function - I get the correct token from backend application.
But everytime in this program , even when I get the incorrect token - the program moves to StudentLobby (and that need to happen only when i get the correct token).

what i'm missing?

[Login function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HMjR.png)

[return html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga39U.png)

```
                               .
```

Comment: What do you mean by an invalid token ? empty string  or null or undefined ?

Comment: when the username and password correct- it's return to me the correct token,
else - it's return http status 400 - bad request

Comment: you are setting the invalid token into the state variable. The condition to display the StudentLobby is that if the token value is not an empty string, it would display StudentLobby. Be careful, this condition will be true even for null and undefined as well. So add a check if (resp?.token &&  resp.token !== "your-invalid token") { setToken(resp.token) }

Comment: if you are getting 400 then check for resp.status. if (resp.status === 200) { setToken(resp.token) }

Comment: then check for the status in the response, and based on that set a token

Comment: where in my code to add the check? in my return of html page , or after fetch function?

Comment: - Add complete api response and code so that required changes can be analyzed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-router` for managing the routing-related stuff.

Here is [doc](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

Example :

https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow

You store your token and manage it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to validate the token before you render the StudentLobby component. If your backend is giving you an expired token it will move on to StudentLobby component anyways, because it is !=="".

If you change your backend response so it only gives you a token if user is authenticated and "" otherwise, your code should work. But if it gives you some string response with a length even when user is not authenticated it won´t.